# Why we use Left Join & Right Join differently? We can get same output from Left Join and also Right Join

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have two tables **[1.Employees 2.Orders.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYFgy.png)**
I execute Left Join and Right Join queries differently when I change positions of table name then I got same output so why we use Left Join & Right Join differently?

Right Join Query

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID,Employees.EmployeeID, Employees.LastName, 
Employees.FirstName
FROM Employees
Right JOIN Orders 
ON Orders.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID
ORDER BY Orders.OrderID;
```

Left Join Query

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Employees.EmployeeID, Employees.LastName, 
Employees.FirstName
FROM Orders
Left JOIN Employees 
ON Orders.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID
ORDER BY Orders.OrderID;
```

[Output of both queries will same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYFgy.png)

Comment: There is no difference. It's merely syntax. You generally don't see many Right Joins out in the wild (except in machine produced code like Business Objects which LOVES its Right Joins).

Comment: To get the same result between Left and Right Join query, you need to change both the table order and the join type. But you get different result if you change only one of them. So basically you use left vs right join based on how you want the query result look like.

Comment: IANAL so I can't tell if I can copy content from Quora, but see the section "But why do both flavors exist?" at [Database Systems: What are the differences between a left join and a right join?](https://www.quora.com/Database-Systems-What-are-the-differences-between-a-left-join-and-a-right-join) which gives one reason.

Comment: I got solution If we want to join third table then we have to write left join and right join to get particular output. Then output will be different.

Answer (score 1):

---

It is the same, since you change positions of the tables.
Most people prefer the left join, because you can easily read the 'from tableA' as tableA being (visually) the 'primary' table. 
Since that's the one that shows all its results in the left join (even if there's no data about certain records in the other table).

Answer (score -1):

To answer this correctly, we need to consider some points like normalization and how well the tables are maintained in terms of NULL values are relations with each other.
Theoretically, A left join B and B right join A should return same values but practically, that is possible only when the tables are maintained properly, NULLs are handled properly as well as Normalization is also taken into consideration. Otherwise unexpected outputs will be printed while using B right join A and that maybe the reason is that left join is preferred as it is easily readable and making more sense.

It will not be possible to verify the differences between these two with the example given in the question but this needs a specific example considering the points mentioned in my answer above.